# clang++ 14 does not generate PDB file

Tags: windows, clang, llvm, pdb-files

## My objective

I want to generate the PDB file of my app using clang++ 14.0.6 and mingw ucrt (the GCC-like) and **NOT** clang-cl / clang-cpp.

## My problem

The PDB file is not generated.

## What I tried

```
clang++ -march=native -O3 -g -gcodeview main.cpp -o filecomp.exe
```

I looked for info in --help, clang github issues and existing SO questions but didn't find any answer so far.
Most people talk about old versions of Clang which solutions didn't work for me or Clang-cl or even visual studio bundled clang-cl which are irrelevant to my case.

Comment: A strange combination. You want to build using mingw ecosystem, but then debug in VS debugger?

Comment: No, I want to use RemedyBG. And it needs PDB files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-g -gcodeview` when compiling, then `-fuse-ld=lld -g -Wl,--pdb=` when linking. This produces `??.pdb` alongside `??.exe`.

You can also pass a custom PDB file path to `-Wl,--pdb=??`.

<sup>I'm unsure if `-g` does anything when linking, but the Clang doesn't warn about it, so I prefer to keep it. It does warn about `-gcodeview` being unused if specified when linking.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the input. What about if I want to compile and link in one go ? Since I have only one source file.

Also can you give the full syntax for the linking part with several object files. I tried ld.lld -o app.exe obj1 obj2 ... but it complains 

ld.lld: error: main.obj: unknown file type

even though help says USAGE: ld.lld.exe [options] file...

I compiled the object file the classic way clang++ -c main.cpp -o main.obj

And finally last question: where did you find that Wl information ? I spent a hour on google and never saw it.

Comment: `clang++ main.obj -o main.exe -fuse-ld=lld -g -Wl,--pdb=` to link. `clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -g -gcodeview -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--pdb=` to compile and link in one go. FYI in mingw ecosystem, the customary object file extension is `.o`, not `.obj`. *"where did you find that Wl information"* Google led me [here](https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/blob/master/README.md#pdb-support). What can I say, my google-fu is better than yours. :P

Comment: I just attempted this for creating a DLL, and I had to manually add these options. Cmake would not add them when put into add_linker_options() for some reason.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that lld was not part of the clang package - you need to use pacman to install lld

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `--pdb=` Holy hell, THANK you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your main CMakeLists.txt

```
add_compile_options(-g -gcodeview)
add_link_options(-fuse-ld=lld -g -Wl,--pdb=)
```