# PDB File Generated Under Clang Missing Source Information with Visual Studio 2022 Community

Tags: c, clang

I am trying to debug a C project built under MSYS2/MinGW with the Clang64 environment, up until now I have debugged with Visual Studio Code with the Clang64 `gbd` binary and have thus compiled with the `-ggdb` option, however I would like to go on to another debugger like Visual Studio 2022 or RemedyBg.

My problem is that `clang` does not produce a PDB file that contains the source information, similar to `cl` with the `/Zi` or `/Z7` options. After looking through Stack Overflow I found out that you have to add the `-g` and `-gcodeview` options to the compiler arguments and doing so increase the size of the end PDB file, by about double, however loading it in VS still results in missing source information.

Command used for compilation is as follows:
(For the sake of legibility parts of the command have been trimmed)

```
 clang $WARNING_OPTS -g -std=c11 -O0 -gcodeview $INCLUDE -o bin/main.exe #SOURCE_FILES $LIB -DSDL -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--pdb=
```

As mentioned previously I have tried to the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416539/clang-14-does-not-generate-pdb-file) however it did not work. Also to note I have tried adding `-gfull` with no luck along with `-gno-column-info` from [this source](https://handmade.network/forums/t/3169-clang_on_windows,_debugging,_compile_times)  again with no luck.

I have tried specifying `-g`, `-gfull` and even `-gcodeview` after the `-fuse-ld` option to no avail and I have not tried linking and compiling separately as of now.

Furthermore I have tried clang-cl from the MinGW64 environment however that then gives me error for not having found a VS installation (even after running vcvarsall x64) along with a compilation error of not finding `stdio.h`. As seen below

```
clang-cl: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
src/main.c(1,10): fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I should note that I have not tried linking separately.

What, if anything, is am I failing to do in my original clang command? Is the command itself wrong or is what I want to merely impossible from MSYS2? Or am I misunderstanding how PDB files work and that they are capable?